# what to use with "your address", at or on?

Tags: prepositions

what should we use with the word "your home", at or on?

for example- I have placed an order .... your address

Comment: "At". You would only use "on your address" when dropping bombs.

Comment: @Digital Chris: In context, ***at*** would probably be understood (but it might also mean *"While I was in your house I placed an order to be delivered to me at my address"*, for example). I'd probably go for ***against*** if I wanted to be more precise about the intended meaning *("I ordered something which will be delivered to your address")*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Great point. "While **at** my address I placed an order for some bombs to be delivered **from** my address **to** FumbleFingers' address, so he can drop bombs **on** Vikas' address."

Answer (score 2):

The choice of preposition, and the context in which it is used, can dramatically alter the meaning of the sentence.

> I placed an order ... your address.

- **at:** I was present in your house when I placed the order.
- **from:** I sent the order from your house.
- **in:** *This one is unidiomatic* I was present in your house when I placed the order. *We would normally say “in your house,” not “in your address”.*
- **inside:** I have taken the order to your house and put it inside.
- **outside:** I was present at the address but outside it when I placed the order, ***or*** I have taken the order to your house and left it outside.
- **to:** *This one is unidiomatic, but could be interpreted as assigning your address as the delivery address on an order.*

- **on:** To place an order on an address means that you are applying an edict or instruction to that property, such as a demolition order (an instruction to demolish).
- **against** could mean the same as *to* or *on*.

There are many other prepositions; these are just a few. With the possible exception of *to,* **any** of them could be used and make sense, but the resulting sentence may not mean what you intend. The context of the sentence could alter the meaning implied by each preposition too.

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on what you're trying to say.

"I have placed an order *at* your home address" implies that someone currently in that house/apartment/etc. placed an order.

"I have placed and order *to* your home address" is probably what you're looking for. That is saying that an order was placed and it will be delivered to your home address.

"I have placed an order *on* your home address" is (I assume) not what you want to say. That pretty much means and sounds like you ordered it while on the roof, or implies that something is going to be delivered to the roof! Haha.